# jQuery a problem with retrieving an element's id

Tags: jquery

in the code below, I need to get the ID of the element that has raised the event

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(".selectors").live('change', function () 
    {
        $.post("GetCategoriesByParentId/", { ID: $(this).val() }, function (data) 
        {
            var idd = $(this).attr('id'); //here
        });
    });
});
```

but the `idd` is always 'Undefined'. Why ?

Comment: the HTML to which the change event is bound would be useful.

Comment: In that context/scope, wouldn't this be the post object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of the `$.post` callback, the value of `this` will be set to something different to that of the `live` call.  You'll need to cache the value of `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $(".selectors").live('change', function () 
    {
        var idd = this.id;

        $.post("GetCategoriesByParentId/", { ID: $(this).val() }, function (data) 
        {
            // idd is now the id of the changed element
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$(this)` inside your `.post` function is not actually the current element in the set you're iterating through in the parent loop. Fix:

```
$(".selectors").live('change', function () 
{
    $thisElement = $(this);

    $.post("GetCategoriesByParentId/", { ID: $(this).val() }, function (data) 
    {
        var idd = $thisElement.attr('id'); //here
    });
});
```